# Google Sheet - Conditional formatting script don't apply

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I tried to create conditional formatting by using script ( because when someone copy and paste a cell, the rule of this cell is pasted too and rules became wtf quickly)

[image]

Here the list of the six rules, the thing is **they all work well if i create them manually.**

As you can see on the next picture, only the 6th rules work if i use the script and i don't know why only the 6th and not the others.

[image]

For 1st to 5th rules, i have to do a modification on the range of the rule,  like, for the first rule, "A:A1000" to "A:A100", wait for the sheet calculation ( rule now work ) then modify the range again to "A:A1000" to apply it for all the range.

[image]

I've search everywhere on the web but found nothing about this bug, am i the only one :O ?!

Here a sample of my script :

```
  function FormatSheet() {
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Test");
var rangea  = sheet.getRange("A:A")
var rangeb  = sheet.getRange("B:B")
var rangec  = sheet.getRange("C:C")
var ranged  = sheet.getRange("D:D")
var rangee  = sheet.getRange("E:E")
var rangef  = sheet.getRange("F:F")
var rangeg  = sheet.getRange("G:G")
var rangeh  = sheet.getRange("H:H")
var rangei  = sheet.getRange("I:I")
var rangej  = sheet.getRange("J:J")
var rangek  = sheet.getRange("K:K")
var rangel  = sheet.getRange("L:L")
var rangem  = sheet.getRange("M:M")
var rangen  = sheet.getRange("N:N")
var rangeo  = sheet.getRange("O:O")
var rangep  = sheet.getRange("P:P")
var rangeq  = sheet.getRange("Q:Q")
var ranger  = sheet.getRange("R:R")
var ranges  = sheet.getRange("S:S")
var ranget  = sheet.getRange("T:T")
var rangeu  = sheet.getRange("U:U")
var rangev  = sheet.getRange("V:V")
var rangew  = sheet.getRange("W:W")
var rangex  = sheet.getRange("X:X")
var rangey  = sheet.getRange("Y:Y")
var rangez  = sheet.getRange("Z:Z")
  //var range3 = sheet.getRange("A1:T1");
  
  sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();

  
  var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=ET(REGEXMATCH($M1;"ABC*");NBCAR($M1)=8)=VRAI')
    .setBackground("#c9daf8")
    .setRanges([rangea,rangeb])
    .build();
  var rules2 = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules2.push(rule2);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules2);

  
    var rule22 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=ET(REGEXMATCH($M1;"ABC*");NBCAR($M1)=8)=VRAI')
    .setBackground("#c9daf8")
    .setRanges([rangec])
    .build();
  var rules22 = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules22.push(rule22);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules22);

    var rule11 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=ET(B1="";C1="")=VRAI')
    .setBackground("#b7b7b7")
    .setRanges([rangea,rangeb,rangec,ranged,rangee,rangef,rangeg,rangeh,rangei,rangej,rangek,rangel,rangem,rangen,rangeo,rangep,rangeq])
    .build();
  var rules11 = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules11.push(rule11);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules11);

      var rule3 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=R:R=AUJOURDHUI()')
    .setBackground("#ff9900")
    .setRanges([rangea])
    .build();
  var rules3 = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules3.push(rule3);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules3);

        var rule4 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=J1<>""')
    .setBackground("#4b88e4")
    .setRanges([rangej,rangek])
    .build();
  var rules4 = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules4.push(rule4);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules4);
  
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried putting ````SpreadsheetApp.flush()```` after each set conditional format rule statement? Changing format of lots of cells using script takes a lot of time so the script may have to apply the format first and wait before creating the next rule.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank for your answer, i've tried SpreadsheetApp.flush() without success. I tried Utilities.sleep(5000) before each flush too but nothing has changed.

Comment: I've separated each rule to create one function for each one to do some tests and, i don't know why, but only the rule4 work right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The conditional formats did not apply correctly upon code execution because the formula names are non-English, when you manually enter (or change) the custom formula, it converts itself into English names and the format proceeds as usual.

### Solution:

You need to enter the English formula names into the code:

```
=AND(REGEXMATCH($M1;"ABC*");LEN($M1)=8)=TRUE
```

```
=AND(B1="";C1="")=TRUE
```

```
=R:R=TODAY()
```

**Sample Output upon code execution:**

[image]

Comment: Thx ! it's worked right away !

I've translated all my formula into the code to english, google sheet translate right back the formula to french in Sheet but they all work.